# Generate postscript file PS-Adobe EPSF android

Tags: android, postscript, eps

Hi Currenlty i'm generating postscript file in android, It's printed as colored. I want to print in black & white. I tried "/DeviceGrey" but got an error.
Can anyone help me out?

```
        wr("%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0");
        wr("%%BoundingBox: 0 0 " + width + " " + height);
        // wr("%%Title: otz.bunny.jpeg");
        // wr("%%Creator: James's JPEG encapsulator - /home/james/etc/jpeg2eps");
        wr("%%CreationDate: " + new Date());
        wr("%%LanguageLevel: 2");
        wr("%%Pages: 1");
        wr("%%EndComments");
        wr("%%Page: 1 1");
        wr("/WIDTH " + width + " def");
        wr("/HEIGHT " + height + " def");
        wr("/DPI " + dpi + " def");
        wr("DPI dup scale");
        wr("/DeviceGray setcolorspace");
        wr("<<");
        wr(" /ImageType 1");
        wr(" /Width WIDTH");
        wr(" /Height HEIGHT");
        wr(" /BitsPerComponent 8");
        wr(" /Decode [0 1]");
        wr(" /ImageMatrix [DPI 0 0 DPI neg 0 HEIGHT]");
        wr(" /DataSource currentfile /ASCII85Decode filter << >> /DCTDecode filter");
        wr(">>");
        wr("image");
```

I'm converting Bitmap to GrayScale image:

```
public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal) {
        int width, height;
        height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
        width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();
        Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(0);
        ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
        paint.setColorFilter(f);
        c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
        return bmpGrayscale;
    }
```

Getting Offending command: O8f3g-d

This error text is part of the bitmap outputstram.

[image]

I visualized ps data PostScript Viewer, But the image getting cropped.
If I use /DeviceGray  /Decode [0 1 0 1 0 1] then image is not cropped.
So can't understand where is the problem.

[image]

Comment: You are rendering an image, if you want it to be monochrome then you will have to convert the coloured bitmap to a grayscale. **Then** you will need to set the colour space to DeviceGray instead of DeviceRGB. Since you haven't said what error you encountered, its not possible to tell you what else is wrong.

Comment: Hi @KenS,
 I have converted the bitmap to grayscale bitmap, But getting Offending Command error.

Comment: Then you have too much image data. When the image operator finishes consuming the required amount of image data, the interpreter picks up interpretation at the next byte of input. Since this is 8-bit data the amount of data in the image should be width * height bytes. Note that you have applied both the ASCII85 and DCT decoding filters. so I can't tell what the correct amount of data should be. I do wonder if the grayscale image data is DCT encoded though.

Comment: Hi @KenS
I have updated the question.
I have visualized ps data. but the image getting cropped.

Comment: However you aren't getting an error now so presumably your original question is now answered. I can't diagnose a problem from a picture, and it doesn't contain a complete source listing anyway.  The way to post code is to put the code in the question, as text, or link to an external source if it's too large. Don't put pictures of code. And the display on the right appears to be of a PDF, not an EPS. I'd guess whatever created the PDF file hasn't honoured the BoundingBox comments of the EPS (or possibly those are incorrect). Changing the Decode array should have no effect